# SQLite time insert query

Tags: sqlite

I want to insert time value to SQLite. I searched about functions, modifiers, timestrings but I could not achieve to my aim. When I write my query, this does not record the '.323', only records '08:25:01'. I want to record '08:25:01.323'. My query is:

```
insert into table_name (column_name) values (time('08:25:01.323'))
```

I'm waiting for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the time as a string and only parse it whe necessary.

```
sqlite> create table t (t text);
sqlite> insert into t values ('08:25:01.323');
sqlite> select * from t;
08:25:01.323
sqlite> select t, time(t) from t;
08:25:01.323|08:25:01
```

Comment: As I understand, I record '08:25:01.323' as text field. With the select command in the end, I obtain '08:25:01' as time field. But, I should record '08:25:01.323' as time area initially, not text. Is this possible?

Comment: SQLite doesn't care about types.